# Split comma separated values and add them to array

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i=0; countn=dropDownValues.length, i<countn; i++){
        if (name == dropDownValues[i].id) {
            var address = dropDownValues[i].shipTo;
            var array = new Array();
            array = address.split(",");
            alert(array.length + " array length")
            for(var n=0; countn=array.length, n<countn; i++){
                alert("in the function loop");
                alert(array[n]);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this part of my function it seems to be getting all the way to the `address.split(",")` but not any further. I added an alert to see the length but it doesn't return anything.

What could be wrong? I'm positive the `address` variable has a value assigned like "one,two" but it isn't getting split.

Comment: How about doing a console.log(address) before the split to make sure there is actually something to split?

Comment: Check your [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: And you could change your for loop to be `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

Comment: Look at the developer console. I am sure there is an error message.

Comment: After fixing your for loops, you'll find out, that using the same variable name (`i`, `countn`) in both loops will mess the looping.

Comment: Please don't fix your code example according to answers. It makes difficult for future readers to understand, why the answers were given in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value I was assigning to address wasn't a string. I needed to use String() on the value to get the string.split() to work correctly

Answer (score 3):

In both your for loop, you have an issue

```
for(var i = 0; countn = array.length, i < countn
```

is wrong;

should be

```
for(var i = 0, countn = array.length; i < countn;
```

---

Next issue is you have a loop with `i` and an inner loop that redefines `i`

```
for (var i = 0; countn = dropDownValues.length, i < countn; i++) {
    ...
    for (var i = 0; countn = array.length, i < countn; i++) {
```

Both loops can not use `i` and `countn`.

```
var count1 = dropDownValues.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
    ...
    var count2 = array.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < count2; j++) {
```

Comment: The first "issue" is not an error (but is confusing and inefficient). The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates all comma-separated expressions and returns the value of the last one.

Comment: @Teemu. Please explain.

Comment: @epascarello I made the changes to the loop and added an alert to see if my array has a length. Turns out it doesn't. The value I'm splitting definitely has 2 comma seperated values that should be getting split. I can output it pre-split

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. `arr[i]` should be `array[i]`.